# ScheduleExpression between exact hours and minutes

Tags: java, timer, ejb, scheduling

I'm working with javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression and timers to create daily scheduled jobs. I need to specify the working time with hours and minutes. For example, lets say that I want it to run "**every day between 18:27-19:47**". How can I write this expression?

I've tried it as follows;

```
ScheduleExpression()
            .hour("18"-"19")
            .minute("27"-"47")
            .second("*")
```

But the problem is that, when I run this, it stops at 18:47 and starts again at 19:27. So, how can I make it run every second in between those hours and minutes?

Also, I want to be able to stop the timer at any point, which I'm doing with "timer.cancel();" method, and then reschedule it for the same hours again, but this time for the next day. Is it somehow possible to write an expression that will start to run next day and keep running at specified hours until it is canceled again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how `ScheduleExpression` is intended to be used, AND you also have a problem with how you define the expression.

```
ScheduleExpression()
            .hour(18-19)
            .minute(27-47)
            .second("*")
```

First, the specification `.hour(18-19)` evaluates to `.hour(-1)`, and `.minute(27-47)` is equivalent to `.minute(-20)`, neither of which is valid.

So I'll assume you really meant (notice the quotes):

```
ScheduleExpression()
            .hour("18-19")
            .minute("27-47")
            .second("*")
```

The points at which a `Timer` "expires" (i.e. fires) are based on the `ScheduleExpression`.  Your expression means whenever

- The hour is 18 or 19
- The minute is any value between 27 and 47 inclusive
- Every second

So you'll get timer expirations at

```
18:27:00
18:27:01
18:27:02
...
18:47:58
18:47:59
then nothing until
19:27:00
19:27:01
...
19:47:58
19:47:59
```

You didn't provide enough detail to understand your intentions, but I don't believe this matches what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the quotes. So, it is not possible to get what I want with ScheduleExpression. Do you have any suggestions to use instead of it?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  The phrase _"every day between 18:27-19:47"_ is ambiguous.  Is it _"Run once a day at some random time between 18:27 and 19:47"_?  If not, then what, exactly do you mean?

Comment: What I exactly want is; "Run every second in between 18:27 and 19:47" and this applies for each day. So 7 days a week, it will start at 18:27 and end at 19:47. During the period, the method will be executed for each second.